# Swift UIAlert disappearing immediately on its own

Tags: ios, swift

I've been using this displayAlert function in my code all over and it's been working as expected just perfectly but now all of a sudden in my latest view controller it isn't functioning properly.

It will display the alert then it will close on it's own within a split second after appearing.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the function code

```
   //This function displays an alert message
func displayAlert(title: String, msg: String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }))

    //Support display in iPad
    alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0, 1.0, 1.0)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And here is the button action that executes when a button is pressed to display the UIAlert.

```
     //Display alert message with avaiability per location
@IBAction func availability(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.displayAlert("Availability per location", msg: "Bellwood: September through April only\nBolingbrook: Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Friday\nChicago: Sundays\nHighland Park: Saturdays\nVilla Park: Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday")
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my back button which will dismissviewcontroller

```
 //Go back to previous view controller
@IBAction func back_btn(sender: AnyObject) {
     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Try removing the line self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

Comment: The problem still persists

Comment: did you try to move `addAction` expression outside the declaration of the alert

Comment: So move it into viewdidload or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: If you are dismissing a controller from any where in code it will dismiss the popupview

Comment: My back button dismisses the view controller so it will return to the last view in the storyboard.  Is that causing the error ? If so how would I solve this because I need that back button

Comment: Yup you were right I commented out my back button code and it works now.  How can I implement my back button now though? I thought it had to dismissViewController and not segue back to the previous view controller to prevent using up a bunch of memory?

Comment: I don't have a navigation controller in my storyboard so I'm not really sure how to go back without dismissing view controller as most answers I've found on google suggest navigation.popviewcontroller